# Sqoop - Import all tables from mysql to hive

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop, hiveql

I have three tables in my mysql db:

`parent_table` with two join tables: `foo`, `bar`, where `parent_table` has many `foo`'s and `bar`'s and `foo`, `bar` belong to `parent_table`.

How can I use sqoop, or an alternative method to import these tables into hive to be queried.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example:

```
sqoop import-all-tables \
  --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
  --username=retail_dba \
  --password=cloudera \
  --warehouse-dir=/user/hive/warehouse/retail_stage.db
```

retail_db in --connect clause is mysql database
retail_dba in --username clause is mysql user who have access to read tables under retail_db mysql database
cloudera in --password clause is password for mysql user retail_dba
/user/hive/warehouse/retail_stage.db in --warehouse-dir is hadoop directory (in this case it is hive database, one can have any valid hadoop directory).
Above script will create directory for each of the mysql table under /user/hive/warehouse/retail_stage.db.

You can run this script as is in Cloudera Quickstart VM.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by taking a look into [Sqoop User Guide](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html) that describes how to use Sqoop or more use case oriented book [Apache Sqoop Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920029519.do). Both sources should be able to help you understand what needs to be done for this case.